# ./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular13

I am using Angular 13.3.9. My error is in

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i23.InputsModule to symbol
    at C:\Users\99906081\Downloads\EIPHRMUI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i23.InputsModule to symbol
    at C:\Users\99906081\Downloads\EIPHRMUI\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

[image]

[image]

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "eiphrmui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "^0.1402.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.8",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^13.3.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.11",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.27",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.8.6",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^11.0.3",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^12.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^8.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^7.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^7.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^7.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-editor": "^4.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^5.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^7.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^4.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "^6.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^4.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^7.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^5.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.12",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^5.5.0",
    "adal-angular": "^1.0.18",
    "adal-angular4": "^9.0.0-beta.0",
    "angular-dropdown": "^0.5.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "commonmodules": "file:cc-packs/commonmodules-13.0.0.tgz",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "eip-bubbletooltip": "file:cc-packs/eip-bubbletooltip-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eip-calculator": "file:cc-packs/eip-calculator-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eip-help-document": "file:cc-packs/eip-help-document-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eip-notes": "file:cc-packs/eip-notes-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eip-tooltip": "file:cc-packs/eip-tooltip-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipalert-with-trace": "file:cc-packs/eipalert-with-trace-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipauto-complete": "file:cc-packs/eipauto-complete-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipcart": "file:cc-packs/eipcart-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipcommon-services": "file:cc-packs/eipcommon-services-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipconfirmation-list-message-box": "file:cc-packs/eipconfirmation-list-message-box-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipdate-picker": "file:cc-packs/eipdate-picker-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipdate-range-picker": "file:cc-packs/eipdate-range-picker-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipdiscussion-forum": "file:cc-packs/eipdiscussion-forum-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipdivpftrace": "file:cc-packs/eipdivpftrace-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipdocument-view": "file:cc-packs/eipdocument-view-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipdocumentupload": "file:cc-packs/eipdocumentupload-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipexcel-upload": "file:cc-packs/eipexcel-upload-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipfooter": "file:cc-packs/eipfooter-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipgeneral-cart": "file:cc-packs/eipgeneral-cart-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipgrid-settings": "file:cc-packs/eipgrid-settings-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipheader": "file:cc-packs/eipheader-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipmessage-box": "file:cc-packs/eipmessage-box-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipmulti-select-auto-complete": "file:cc-packs/eipmulti-select-auto-complete-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipnumeric": "file:cc-packs/eipnumeric-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eippdf-view": "file:cc-packs/eippdf-view-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipsend": "file:cc-packs/eipsend-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eiptab-message-box": "file:cc-packs/eiptab-message-box-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eiptext-box": "file:cc-packs/eiptext-box-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eiptoast-alert": "file:cc-packs/eiptoast-alert-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipwfsend-back": "file:cc-packs/eipwfsend-back-13.0.0.tgz",
    "eipwftrace": "file:cc-packs/eipwftrace-13.0.0.tgz",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "iv-viewer": "^2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng-image-slider": "^1.3.7",
    "ng-wormhole": "^3.0.2",
    "ng2-image-viewer": "^3.0.5",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^9.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-observable": "0.0.7",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.11",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.13",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "EIPHRMUI": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": { },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/EIPHRMUI",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/ng2-image-viewer/imageviewer.scss",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "angular-slickgrid", "stream"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "EIPHRMUI:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "EIPHRMUI:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "EIPHRMUI:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "EIPHRMUI",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "80f88efa-5d5c-43bc-a939-ea338d7d3ed4",
    "defaultCollection": "@ngrx/schematics",
    "cache": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some context as to what your problem is :)

Comment: Where are you using the `InputsModule` which has been mentioned by the error message?

Comment: I didnot use any InputsModule.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I resolved by installing the Angular Compiler Webpack Plugin using the command:

`npm i @ngtools/webpack`